# Java regular expression - Replace a expression until a word boundary

Tags: regex

I want to remove the word "object" until the beginning of word "date"
For example, for this: `blablaobjectthisisatestdateblabla`

I want this:
`blabladateblabla`

I tried to use this expression by group `(.*)(object)(.*)(date)(.*)` to be replaced by `$1$4$5` but it didn't work, any idea?

Comment: Search using `object.*date` and replace with `""`

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: @William That will delete `date` also. The OP wants to delete from `object` up to but not including `date`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete from `object` up to `date` but not including `date`, then using a lookahead assertion is one way:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s =  "blablaobjectthisisatestdateblabla";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("object[\\s\\S]*(?=date)");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        s = m.replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
blabladateblabla
```

The regex:

```
object      # matches object
[\s\S]*     # matches 0 or more whitespace or non-whitespace characters (. will not match the newline)
(?=date)    # until the next characters are 'date'
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/INYPxk/1/)